# A better way to mark location on a map

Tags: ios, user-interface, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm making an iOS app, where I want users to mark locations on a regular basis on a map. The default way to mark location in iOS is to drop a pin either at the center of the map or where the user holds a touch (using the gesture recognizer).

Then to mark the pin to the desired location **ACCURATELY**, the user holds the pin and can drop it again. If you have done this on an iOS maps app, you will know it is hard to mark a location **ACCURATELY**, in this manner. It looks cool, but takes some trial and error in my opinion.

If I can help it, I want to make this process smoother and more obvious is my app. 
**So is there any other way for the user to mark a location on a map, without doing the default pin drag-drop? Any Suggestions welcome :-)**

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea... instead of moving the pin, you could move the map with the finger, and keep the pin always in the middle of the mapView (maybe marked with a crosshair or something). Then you can get the coordinates of the Pin using the "center" method of the mapView. That way you don't cover the pin / crosshair with your finger.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a look at the Maps app again. When you hold down your finger on a dropped pin, notice the location of bottom of the pin on the map. The pin actually drops in this exact location, after doing a quick bounce. The pin also sits about 20 above the users finger.

While it's not the most obvious, it's very accurate in my opinion. Enough to query the Geocoder API for an address, or just get coordinates. Keep in mind the GPS has an accuracy of 5-10 meters at the most. Zooming in will allow the user to go even more accurate.

But if this solutions isn't what you want, I'd overlay a point in the centre of the map and make sure it doesn't respond to touches, making it possible to move around the map underneath this point. When touched end, then drop a pin in the middle of the map where the point is. If touches begin again, pop out the pin from the map. I don't think a pin that's already on the map staying in place while the map moves independently will look good.

Comment: ya pin staying statically in the middle, like on the yelp app looks a bit "hacky". having an overlay point is more legit! Thanks!